# Riley Riddle for Your Peace of Mind

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is another Riley Riddle for you all:

> The prefix will come to you in a bit of time
>
> The infix is a miracle to those nearing the end of their line
>
> Onto the suffix, teeny tiny, something small
>
> Put it together and you have something important to all

Good Luck Everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Security

The prefix will come to you in a bit of time

> **Sec** - short for second

The infix is a miracle to those nearing the end of their line

> **Cur**(e) - the way it's pronounced sounds like cure which would be a miracle for those near death.

Onto the suffix, teeny tiny, something small

> **Ity** - sounds like 'itty'  meaning small.

Put it together and you have something important to all

> Security is important to everybody.

Title

> Security provides peace of mind.

Comment: If this is the answer, I was thinking of making a Riley Riddle of this word, but could not explain the suffix. I'm glad someone did it, and that someone *answered* it too, most likely :P